# More Twilio details required

Tags: twilio

I'd like to start using Twilio portal to send Whatsapp messages and/or SMS.
For SMS I didn't find particular problem, whilst for Whatsapp I found that there are many things to consider.
Before buying some credit on Twilio site I need to get answer to all my following questions :

1) I'd like to customize my Whatsapp icon by changing the Twilio logo: is it possible ?
2) I understood the sandbox for Whatsapp is not intended for "production" use, it's only for test uses.
...so the use of international Whatsapp number should stop and this is good for me; it seems that 
the use of sandbox could finish when some approvals of Mr. Whatsapp should happen, but I can't understand what Whatsapp
should approve.
3) Should I have a new Italian mobile number to bind to Whatsapp Twilio services to get an Italian number for
Whatsapp reaching my customers ?
4) Should I create a Facebook profile... I'm only developing for a possible business (but not mine) and I don't want
to bother myself with Facebook.
5) Can I send ads and/or reminders to my 1000 customers via whatsapp with Twilio ? I don't want to bother my customers with :
"please register ..." or "join my sandbox" or whatelse. I don't want Whatsapp block my account too because of
something that I didn't understand : "opt-in", I read somewhere on Twilio website.
6) I'd like to send a picture with my business logo to my Whatsapp customer, but the mediaUrl only accepts http or https; I loaded
my picture in the Assets area, but as I read, anybody could reach that picture and that is not very beautyful. I changed to 
private asset my picture, but in such case the resource has no longer an http/https prefix, how can I reach my private picture ?
could I load my picture from my disk with Python ?
7) I don't want to manage inbound messages (neither SMS, nor Whatsapp), since if somebody send me a reply that cost me, I'd like
to disallow inbound messages, is it possible ?

Thanks.

Over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

1. When you are approved to use the API by WhatsApp, you will get [a new business profile which you will be able to use your own images for](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api#how-your-business-appears-to-users).
2. WhatsApp are rolling out access to the API in a controlled manner. To get approved you need to [request access to the WhatsApp API](https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp/request-access).
3. You will need to purchase a Twilio number that will get enabled as a WhatsApp business number when your request is approved. You can choose whichever country you want as long as Twilio has numbers available in that country.
4. WhatsApp is owned by Facebook and the API is ultimately administered through Facebook. You will need a business profile, but our sales team can help with setting it up.
5. In order to send messages to your users via WhatsApp, WhatsApp's terms state that your users need to opt in to receive those messages. Notably this is not through the use of sending a message saying "join random-words" that is just how the Twilio API for WhatsApp sandbox works. You do have to be able to demonstrate that your users have opted in to receive messages though. Also, with WhatsApp there are further restrictions. If you are outside of a session (which lasts 24 hours since the last message the user sent you) then you can only send messages in pre-approved templates. Once a user replies to you the messages can then be freeform.
6. You can host images behind HTTP basic authentication and then give the url in the format `https://username:password@example.com/image.jpeg`. That way, Twilio can access your image but no-one else can. I don't think it's possible to do that with Twilio Assets though.
7. It's not possible to disallow inbound messages to a WhatsApp number.

Comment: About the opt-in, how does Facebook know that you've really asked your clients to opt-in? I've [read this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/opt-in/) but I'm still unsure how we really implement this function. Do we let the user enter his/her number on our page and store it in a database? Is there an API call that we have to make to notify Facebook that we've complied with the opt-in? How does this really work? I'm thinking about creating an Twilo account for this. because the twilo python api looks nice. But this is opt-in is giving me headaches... thanks.

Comment: How you store your user details is up to you. There is nothing like an API to notify Facebook about opt-ins. At the bottom of that page you linked to it says: "To ensure compliance, we will routinely check a business' opt-in flows. We will also monitor the quality signals you'll see in your WhatsApp Account. When they are red, we will verify that the appropriate opt-in flow is in place." Basically, Facebook is watching you!

Comment: yes I read that but it's still unclear to me how in practice facebook does the audit. They don't have access to our database or the login area of our customer sites, so how does Facebook know that we are complying with the opt-in rules? Do they contact us and we have to show them that we have the pages where our customers actively sign in to get notifications via WhatsApp? Does that page with the opt-in have to be publicly available or is it OK for it to be part of the customer's login area?

Comment: I’m afraid I don’t know any further than what I’ve already said. If you’re worried I would try contacting Facebook directly to try to get the answer from them.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll do that.